# Finding min and max on same iteration in Python

Tags: python, max, min

I have the following code:

```
max=max(len(j.links) for j in roads.junctions())
min=min(len(j.links) for j in roads.junctions())
```

roads.junctions() returns a list with almost 1 million junctions.
Is there a way to find the minimum and the maximum of the items in the same iteration, in one line (instead of writing a function that computes them both)?

Comment: Does it have to be one line? I think you're shooting yourself in the foot a bit on that one.

Comment: I think he means in one loop iteration, but yes, OP, if you could clarify.

Comment: @FrankV Well, he states "in the same iteration, in one line," so I'm assuming he means it literally. I think he's barking up the wrong tree, but that appears to be the tree in question.

Answer (score 7):

You can't get both the minimun and maximum in one line, but you *can* get them with a simple loop:

```
min_value, max_value = float('inf'), float('-inf')
for j in roads.junctions():
    value = len(j.links)
    if value < min_value:
        min_value = value
    if value > max_value:
        max_value = value
```

This produces the values with the same complexity as `min()` and `max()`: O(N), so linear complexity. It also looks at each value in isolation, not requiring all values to be in a single list in memory.

You can always wrap that into a function of course:

```
def min_and_max(iterable):
    min_value, max_value = float('inf'), float('-inf')
    for value in iterable:
        if value < min_value:
            min_value = value
        if value > max_value:
            max_value = value
    return min_value, max_value

min_value, max_value = min_and_max(len(j.links) for j in roads.junctions())
```

Comment: Dam you beat me to it

Comment: can you explain me about `float('inf')` and `float('-inf')` . what the use of it.

Comment: @Hackaholic: float infinity values are guaranteed to be larger or smaller than any other number. So `min_value` is set to `float('inf')` and *any other number* is smaller than that, however large you make it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters +1 for `float('inf')` concept :)

Answer (score 4):

the necessary `reduce` one-liner (just because it is doable in one line):

```
min_v, max_v = reduce(lambda y,x: (min(len(x), y[0]), max(len(x), y[1])), roads.junctions(), (float('inf'), float('-inf')))
```

The lambda takes a argument that has a length, and a tuple of current min/max, and returns the updated tuple. The tuple is initialized with inf/-inf, and the lambda is applied to all items of the iterable passed to `reduce`.